# What does ^ and ! stand for in ANTLR grammar

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr3, antlrworks

I was having difficulty figuring out what does ^ and ! stand for in ANTLR grammar terminology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the [ANTLR Cheat Sheet](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR+Cheat+Sheet):

> `!`    don't include in AST
>   `^`   make AST root node

And `^` can also be used in rewrite rules: `... -> ^( ... )`. For example, the following two parser rules are equivalent:

```
expression
  :  A '+'^ A ';'!
  ;
```

and:

```
expression
  :  A '+' A ';' -> ^('+' A A)
  ;
```

Both create the following AST:

```
  +
 / \
A   A
```

In other words: the `+` is made as root, the two `A`'s its children, and the `;` is omitted from the tree.

Comment: I took the liberty to expand your answer a bit instead of creating an answer myself. Feel free to rephrase it as you see fit, or remove it (in which case I'll create one myself).