# How to use ANTLR for python target?

Tags: python-3.x, installation, antlr3

I'm using ANTLRWorks 1.5.2 for grammar creation and subsequent creation of the lexer and parser. I did that for Java target, but my preferred language is python. I'm quite puzzled by this: how can I specify my target language in ANTLRWorks 1.5.2 and get lexer and parser in python? I read somewhere that antlrworks in just for java target. 
How can I install antlr3 and use python runtime?
I would be really appriciate if anyone can guid me. 
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the following `options {...}` block in your grammar:

```
options {
  language=Python;
}
```

and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> from within ANTLRWorks, the `*.py` lexer and parser files will be generated in the grammar's `output/` directory.

However, debugging from within ANTLRWorks only works with the Java target.

As for a complete Python example, checkout this previous Q&A: [ANTLR get and split lexer content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929797/antlr-get-and-split-lexer-content)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge! I was really stuck at this point, as usual your help was very helpful and wise :)

Comment: Is there any way to get Python lexer and parser in ANTLRWorks 2.1 ?

Comment: No, grammars written for ANTLR3 cannot be used in ANTLRWorks2. ANTLRWorks2 works only with ANTLR4 grammars (and StringTemplates). However, there are [Python-2](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4-python2) and [-3](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4-python3) runtimes for ANTLR4 in the making which can (probably) be used with ANTLRWorks2.

Comment: I have one more question, now I'm using ANTLR and PyDev plugins for eclipse,Is it possible to generate lexer and parser in python language by eclipse?

Comment: could you please tell me which tool is proper for using lexer and parser files in python language? (I want to use these files and execute data from input files)